# How to remux MP4/MKV files using GUI?

Tags: gui, ffmpeg, video-conversion

So I have MKV/MP4 with multiple audio tracks and multiple subtitle tracks.

I want to remux the video so only 1 audio and subtitle is present. On OS X, I currently use a tool called MP4Tools/MKVTools.

It lets me select/tick which tracks I want in the output file. (apologies since I cannot find a video on my Mac that has multiple audio/subtitles).

[image: MP4Tools screenshot]

As can be seen from the screen (one with red line), subtitles are process in 2 ways. burned (video will be reencoded) and mux (video will NOT be reencoded). **--I would like to have both options. And video and audio both have a passthrough option which I would like to have.--**

I've looked at the MP4tools "package" and it seems it's just a frontend to ffmpeg. I'm hoping there's something similar in Linux/Ubuntu.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out mkvtoolnix. Think it might do what you need it to.

https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html#ubuntu

Edit: `sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix mkvtoolnix-gui`

[image]

Comment: from what I understand (since I've used mkvtoolnix on windows), I still need a GUI front-end. MKVToolnix is command-line only. Thanks though :)

Comment: There's a gui. I edited my post to include a screenshot.

Comment: `sudo apt install mkvtoolnix-gui`

Comment: Definitely the easiest way, works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my [dmMediaConverter](https://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html) (ffmpeg GUI) and choose to burn the subtitle because mp4 container does not accest subs. If you choose mkv as output then there is no trouble. Just disable autio streams that you don't need. This process is without reencoding so it is very fast and no quality loss. Enjoy!

[image: dmMEdiaConverter screenshot]

Comment: mp4 can have subtitle tracks inside it. Doesn't have to be burned in. How do I know? I've inserted many many subtitle tracks (most often downloaded from public subtitle sites) using the OS X I mentioned. :)

I'll check out your suggestion! :)

Comment: mdalacu Where can i download it? I tried looking for the app on Ubuntu 16.04.3 and it's not there. I clicked on the link on the website you linked and it gives a 404. thanks

Comment: @mrjayviper
https://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html
You should download the corresponding x86 or x64 DEB file from "Download app (GDrive folder)" link  since Ubuntu software center no longer publishes deb files.... :/
I hope that  that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Handbrake does all these things and more.

Can be installed with `sudo apt-get install handbrake`.

Website : https://handbrake.fr/

Comment: As a regular user of handbrake, I honestly think handbrake --will-- always reencode the audio/video though. I have never seen an option for just remux which I what I want to do. :)

Comment: Ok, I understand that.  However, if you want permanent subtitles, they need to be burned in and the video will be reencoded with subs overlayed.  If you don't want that, then just use a subtitle file and make sure it's in the same folder.  Most video players will use the text-based sub files with no issues.  Handbrake is probably your best bet in Linux.  Not sure if kdenlive has these options you're looking for though.

Comment: I never said I --only-- want permanent (burned in) subtitles. I said I want to have both options :). And even if I use a separate subtitle file. I still need to remux only the audio tracks that I want. And handbrake will never do a "copy". It will always reencoded both audio/video from my experience.